# ¿Mostrar imagenes en template django?

Tags: django, django-templates

estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen en el template en django.

en mi bd, yo tengo un archivo input, sencillo donde guardo el nombre de mi imagen.
mas o menos asi, por registro.

```
> img1.jpg 
  img2.jpg
  etc... et
```

c

Cuando traigo los registros de la bd, y lo recorro con un foreach en el template, todo los atributos los puedo imprimir, como nombre, descripcion, etc. asi por ejemplo:

```
> {{item.nombre}}
  {{item.descripcion}}
 etc... etc..
```

normalmente en la etiqueta de img, yo tengo una carpeta static configurada, y dentro una carpeta img y funciona bien de la siguiente manera:

```
<img src="{% static  'img/img.jpg' %}" alt=""> // me imprime la img correctamente en el template
```

Pero cuando traigo el nombre de la bd, me gustaria poner el nombre de manera dinamica, y no manual
e intentado lo siguiente pero no funciona:

```
<img src="{% static  'img/{{item.imagen}}' %}" alt="">
```

¿como podria hacer?
agradezco de antemano la ayuda.
gracias.

Comment: ¿Has probado `src="{% static '' %}img/{{item.imagen}}"`?

Comment: gracias amigo, me sirvio!
tienes depronto alguna guia, donde pueda hacerlo mas profesional?
de todas maneras muchas gracias!